# Numpy of image> 0

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, ndimage

I first binarized an image and then filtered it in python.

Now how can I add every pixel> 0 to a numpy array?

```
img = Image.open('native.png').convert('RGB')
binarised = img.convert('LA')
# binarised.save('binarised.png')
filtered = ndimage.median_filter(binarised, size = 27)
# Image.fromarray(filtered).save('filtered.png')

width, height = img.size

x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
for column in range(width):
    for line in range(height):
        if(???):              ### if pixel at column/line > 0 ###
            x = np.append(x, column)
            y = np.append(y, line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        if (filtered[column - 1, line - 1] > 0).all():
```

Comment: I get "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" :/

Comment: Edited my answer, should work now, if it works please accept and upvote.

Comment: Sure, already did - thanks man! But now I get another "IndexError: index 529 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 529" :(

Comment: What does `print(filtered.shape)` give?

Comment: It gives (550, 529, 2)

Comment: Updated my answer, try now!

Comment: No :/ I swapped "width" with "height" and now it starts but I'm not sure if he does it correctly :/

Comment: Ah that was what I was gonna edit next